# How localize the Cancel button in SearchControllerDisplay?

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I know how to add and localize a Done button in NavBar when using the SearchBar.
Like this:

```
//Add the done button.
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Text", @"")
                                       style:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone 
                                    target:self action:@selector(doneSearching_Clicked:)] autorelease];
```

}

Now I want to use the same technic to localize the Cancel button in the SearchControllerDisplay.
But how? I know it can be done but I do not find any solution.

Comment: I set up the searchDisplayController programmatically and the Cancel button seems to be there by default even if I don't write any special code for that.  Same thing happens if I do it by the IB. And I want the cancel button where it is, just right of the search window. And it does not change depending of the language, and the Done button did not change either. But I want another text in another language.

Comment: check section "Use Base Internationalization" in this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp.html

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a cancel button you just use UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel instead of UIBarButtonSystemItemDone

Answer (score 0):

you could iterate through the `subviews` of the `UISearchBar` and "find" a `UINavigationButton` and then change the title: `setTitle:`

Comment: //iterate through searchbar subviews and find UIButton to localize it
  UIButton* cancelButton;
  for (UIView* subView in self.searchBar.subviews){
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:UIButton.class]) {
      cancelButton = (UIButton*)subView;
    }
  }
  if (cancelButton)
    [cancelButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel",nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know if you set the button type to be a cancel button, iOS will automatically localize it according to the language of the phone.

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to be the case. I tried the TableSearch sample app by Apple in the simulator, changing language in Settings and relaunch TableSearch gave no effect: http://zomg.se/s/1s/vnf3cazxno0so.png

Comment: Hmm... in Apple's Mail and Contacts apps changing the language has effect on the search display controllers: http://zomg.se/s/9t/idkm77lcg8c4g.png. I'm confused.